# Cannot find symbol EnableJpaRepositories even with build.gradle dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

The following error is appearing in my Spring Boot project. I'm almost there, but I feel like I am missing something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated.

The error is as follows:

```
C:\Users\biz\IdeaProjects\genecab-bank\src\main\java\com\genecab\bank\BankApplication.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
@EnableJpaRepositories
 ^
  symbol: class EnableJpaRepositories
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is my BankApplication.java file:

```
package com.genecab.bank;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class BankApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BankApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.genecab'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Thank you ahead of time for your answer!

I tried running the following command:

```
.\gradlew clean build
```

I expected the following:

```
C:\Users\biz\IdeaProjects\genecab-bank>.\gradlew clean build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 18s
9 actionable tasks: 9 executed
```

Comment: You haven't imported the annotation class. Add `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;` to the import list.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel . I edited the code and still have a similar error. In IntelliJ IDEA it indicates on the import that jpa is in red which means it can't find jpa.

Comment: Try reimporting the Gradle project in IntelliJ (using the refresh button on the Gradle tab).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @MarkRotteveel . It has the same issue after a refresh. Also, the same issue exists from the Windows command prompt as well.

Comment: Check the libraries listed under `compileClasspath` of `.\gradlew dependencies`, it suggests that it doesn't include `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa`, which should be added by `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Or you're looking at/modifying the wrong `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel . `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa` is not found on the compile classpath. Neither is `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. Not sure why they don't show up even though I'm adding them to `implementation` in build.gradle. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, one moment. I changed my build.gradle. Thanks for responses. Give me a moment please.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm past this error now. You were right that I needed to add `import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;` to my .java file. Then I had edited my build.gradle to post my question after I had a problem and then ran into another error, which was then fixed by reverting build.gradle to the way it was in the original question. This is resolved. Thank you so much! @MarkRotteveel